# How to set a default Jasmine timeout and a different timeout for a single spec when using Protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'd like to set a general 10000 millisecond Jasmine timeout for an entire suite when running Protractor tests; however, as the first spec has some set up required I'd like the timeout for this spec to be extended by a further 10000 milliseconds.

I have jasmineNodeOpts defaultTimeoutInterval set to 10000 in the protractor config file, as follows:

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
defaultTimeoutInterval: 10000
}
```

For the first spec, I have included a third argument of 20000 to the it block as follows:

```
it('should allow user to navigate to the homepage', async (done): 
Promise<any> => {
await sideMenuPage.clickMenuItem(sideMenuPage.homeOption);
await secureHomepage.isDisplayed(secureHomepage.accountBreakdown)
  .then(isDisplayed => expect(isDisplayed).toBeTruthy())
  .then(done, done.fail);
  }, 20000);
```

I haven't added a third argument for any further specs.

However, the first spec still experiences a jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL. error after 10000 milliseconds.

Which Jasmine timeout takes precedent? jasmineNodeOpts defaultTimeoutInterval or the third argument of an it block?

Is it possible to have a different Jasmine timeout for one spec within a suite of specs, whilst also using the jasmineNodeOpts defaultTimeoutInterval? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I am also trying to figure out the same. Please let me know  if you find out anything :)